# Limit the number of characters per line editor vi linux

Tags: linux, vim, vi

I am trying that in the editor vi, limit the number of characters per line you can do. Once you reach those x characters, break the line with a carriage return. For example: limit 50 characters.

I have not seen that there is any command (like :set nu to write the numbers of the lines in editor vi) or something similar to activate it.

I know that in order for it to take effect I have to create the file ~/.vimrc but there I don't know how to edit it so that when I later create a file, I restrict it.

Comment: `set textwidth=50`

Answer (score 2):

Are you really using `vi`? You are probably using `vim`. If so, `:help` will answer most of your _I don't know_s. From there, you can also jump to specific parts of the help following the links (you recognize them as they are likely colored, bolded, or highligthed somehow) by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (and yes, you can also enter `:help ctrl-]` to see the help on the key combination I've just mentioned).

In order to do what you want, it is enough that you put `set textwidth=50` or `set tw=50` in your `~/.vimrc` file (note that a value of zero for `tw` means that the option is disabled, or if you prefer, that `tw` is infinite). If you want to look at the description of this option, enter `:help textwidth`.

This setting (`:set tw=50`), however, won't change already existing lines; in order to change all the already existing lines according to the current setting of `tw`, you can do `gggqG`, which moves to the first line (`gg`) and then formats the lines (`gq`, for info enter `:help gq`, which will also reveal the reason why this command will have an effect even if `tw` is 0) till to the last line (`G` moves to last line of file).

Comment: Please, explain the reason for downvoting, so that I can improve my answer.